# Incremental Game Math: Trying to calculate and automate buying as many upgrades as possible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
// CostNextUpgrade[n] simply equals the cost of the next upgrade of upgrade 'n', 
// if n == 0, the buymax boolean = true
if (CostNextUpgrade[UpgradeNumber] <= TotalCash) { AbilityToBuyOne = true; }
if (n == 0) { BuyMax = true; }
else { BuyMax = false; }

// Boolean BuyMax simply states true if they have selected option to buy maximum buildings.
// BUYS MAX AMOUNT OF BUILDINGS
while (BuyMax == true)
{
    // AbilityToBuyOne is determined above if they have the cash to buy 1 upgrade, 
    // this should loop until AbilityToBuyOne becomes false.
    if (AbilityToBuyOne == true)
    {
        TotalCash -= CostNextUpgrade[UpgradeNumber]; //Subtracts cost from total cash
        NumberOwned[UpgradeNumber] += 1; //Increments # owned
    }
}
```

This code snippet is called when a buy button is pressed. If the player wants to buy the maximum amount of 'n' then buy max is set to true by another function. That works fine. My issue is how Unity gives negative to positive infinity errors when I try to use this loop. If I have the $ to buy a small amount of upgrades (1-50ish) then the code works alright. But over that, an error is thrown about decimal math using infinity.

Comment: `while (BuyMax == true)` You don't update `BuyMax` inside the loop, so how will it ever exit? You also don't update `AbilityToBuyOne` in the loop, so that isn't going to change either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your logic all wrong.
You want to loop while the cost of the next upgrade is less than the total cash available AND (BuyMax is true OR NumOfItemsLeftToBuy >= 1)

Take a look at these test methods, this should be able to help you.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {            
            int[] CostNextUpgrade = new int[5];
            int[] NumberOwned = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < CostNextUpgrade.Length; i++)
            {
                CostNextUpgrade[i] = i;
            }

            // Buy the max number of upgrade number 2 then exit
            int n = 0;
            bool BuyMax = n == 0; // BuyMax is true if n == 0
            int UpgradeNumber = 2;
            int TotalCash = 10;


            while (CostNextUpgrade[UpgradeNumber] <= TotalCash && 
                (BuyMax == true || n >= 1))
            {
                TotalCash -= CostNextUpgrade[UpgradeNumber];
                NumberOwned[UpgradeNumber] += 1;
                n--;
            }

            // Assert we can't afford another upgrade
            Assert.IsTrue(TotalCash < CostNextUpgrade[UpgradeNumber]); 
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            int[] CostNextUpgrade = new int[5];
            int[] NumberOwned = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < CostNextUpgrade.Length; i++)
            {
                CostNextUpgrade[i] = i;
            }

            // Buy 3 of upgrade number 2
            int n = 3;
            bool BuyMax = n == 0; // BuyMax is true if n == 0
            int UpgradeNumber = 2;
            int TotalCash = 10;


            while (CostNextUpgrade[UpgradeNumber] <= TotalCash &&
                (BuyMax == true || n >= 1))
            {
                TotalCash -= CostNextUpgrade[UpgradeNumber];
                NumberOwned[UpgradeNumber] += 1;
                n--;
            }

            // Assert we bought exactly 3
            Assert.AreEqual(NumberOwned[UpgradeNumber], 3);
        }
    }
}
```